# Microsoft Graph API - Get directory objects from a list of ids - Bad request

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I need to get a list of groups that the user is a member of using Microsoft Graph API.

For this, I am using the endpoint `POST /users/<userId>/getMemberGroups` ([doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/user_getmembergroups)). This works fine but the problem is that the response is only a list of group object ids. I need to get group properties too. I could just loop through the list and query API for `GET /groups/<groupId>` but this takes too long when the user has multiple groups.

Then I found `POST /directoryObjects/getById` ([doc](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/directoryobject_getbyids)) which turns that list into what I need. I have followed the doc page exactly but I am getting the following error:

*Request_BadRequest - Specified HTTP method is not allowed for the request target.* (HTTP status 405)

What am I doing wrong? Is the method `getById` bugged? If it is, is there any alternative way to turn a list of group object ids into groups or to get full list of user groups?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API [`Get directory objects from a list of ids`](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/api/directoryobject_getbyids) you mentioned should work, I test it in the [MS Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#), it works fine.

Make sure you use `POST` method, I can reproduce your issue with another method.

[image]

You could refer to the informations below and try again.

Request URL:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/directoryObjects/getByIds
```

Request Body:

```
{
  "ids": [
        "xxxxxxxx-9f1b-4f28-a408-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxx-a614-4335-81eb-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxx-e500-49d6-a705-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxx-5be3-41eb-864d-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxx-961d-4db9-87cf-xxxxxxxxxxxx",
        "xxxxxxxx-93bf-4950-8d96-xxxxxxxxxxxx"
  ],
  "types": [
    "group"
  ]
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I tried doing it in Graph Explorer yesterday using POST method and it still failed. Now I tried it again and it worked. I think the explorer might have just bugged out somehow (or I made a typo somewhere...). Thanks! :)